# The C# events implementation (articles vs reflector)

Tags: c#, events

public class EventsType
    {
        public event EventHandler> NewEvent;

```
    public void SmthHappened(string data)
    {
        MyEventArgs<Object> eventArgs = new MyEventArgs<Object>(data);
        OnNewEvent(eventArgs);
    }

    private void OnNewEvent(MyEventArgs<Object> eventArgs)
    {
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs<Object>> tempEvent = NewEvent;

        if (tempEvent != null)
        {                
            tempEvent(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that the C# compiler will translate the NewEvent like this:

```
private EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> _newEvent;

public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> NewEvent
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add
    {
    _newEvent = (EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>>)Delegate.Combine(_newEvent, value);
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove
    {
    _newEvent = (EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>>)Delegate.Remove(_newEvent, value);
    }
}
```

, but the Reflector says that it is implemented this way:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> NewEvent
{
    add
    {
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> handler2;
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> newEvent = this.NewEvent;
        do
        {
            handler2 = newEvent;
            EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> handler3 = (EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>>) Delegate.Combine(handler2, value);
            newEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>>>(ref this.NewEvent, handler3, handler2);
        }
        while (newEvent != handler2);
    }
    remove
    {
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> handler2;
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> newEvent = this.NewEvent;
        do
        {
            handler2 = newEvent;
            EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>> handler3 = (EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>>) Delegate.Remove(handler2, value);
            newEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler<MyEventArgs<object>>>(ref this.NewEvent, handler3, handler2);
        }
        while (newEvent != handler2);
    }
}
```

Please, smb explain me why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup: [C# 4 has made some changes in this area](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/tags/events/), basically. It makes it thread-safe without locking. That's not the only change - it also changes how references to field-like events within the class are resolved: += and -= now go through the "add" and "remove" bits rather than working directly with the backing field.

Note that this change affects code compiled with the C# 4 compiler even against older frameworks; there are also changes to locking which *only* affect code compiled against .NET 4, as it uses a new method ([`Monitor.TryEnter(object, out bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679.aspx)).

Comment: I was just looking at the decompiled source of an event compiled with Roslyn (so C# 6) and I still see the do...while loop with CompareExchange. What version used Monitor.TryEnter()? Do you remember?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question very much depends on the version you're using. It has been refined a lot over the years. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting is a simple non thread safe implementation. The field like event syntax always provide thread-safe syntax (hence the reflector version). Refer this [artcile](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/event_fundamentals.aspx) for understanding events & how they get implemented.